# Get file contents through listbox options

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

i have a listbox into which i get file names by choosing a directory through this code:

```
  private void Button_OpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog OpenFBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (OpenFBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            LBX_Files.Items.Clear();

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(OpenFBD.SelectedPath);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                ListBX.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
            }
        }
    }
```

Now what i want to do is on selection of one of the files, i want to display that chosen files contents into a label.

i tried fiddeling with `label.Text = ListBX.SelectedItem` and   `L_ShowContents.Text = LBX_Files.Items.Add(File.ReadAllText(File));` tried adding `File.ReadAllText()` anywhere i saw logical but that needs a path and i can't seem to get a path in there, even so that there are multiple different files..

Comment: The path is `OpenFBD.SelectedPath`. When you know it there, you just need to remember it a bit longer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, you need to declare `files` array as global field 
and use `SelectedIndexChanged` event in order to listen to the current selected item that the user chooses, using that event you can query your array (that contains the full path) with Linq and then use the full path with `File.ReadAllText()` in order to show file content:

```
 // this array must be declared as global field
 public string[] files;
 private void Button_OpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     FolderBrowserDialog OpenFBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();
     if (OpenFBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         LBX_Files.Items.Clear();

         files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(OpenFBD.SelectedPath);
         foreach (string file in files)
         {
             LBX_Files.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));
         }
     }
 }

 private void LBX_Files_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

         L_ShowContents.Text = File.ReadAllText( files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(LBX_Files.SelectedItem.ToString())));
 }
```

Comment: Yyes you are correct but my wording isnt, i dont want the path to be shown rather when the user selects an item aka a file in the listbox, then the label will show what content that file has

Comment: OK, i have changed the answer in order to read file content using `File.ReadAllText` is that what you need?